# Enthought Traits names limitations?

Tags: python, traits

I ran into a weird problem while trying to build a Traits GUI that relies on Matplotlib.  To summarize it: if, in the example here: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/EmbeddingInTraitsGUI, if I replace everywhere the name of the "figure" trait (which, I thought, was just a property I could name the way I want) by, e.g., "figu", I get the following error: "An error occured creating a custom editor. Please contact the developer."

Am I doing something wrong, or is that limitation documented somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which instances of figure did you change (i.e. which lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to change the line in the `MakePlot` function from

```
fig = editor.object.figure
```

to

```
fig = editor.object.figu
```